# Error Code 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, database

Creating a new database here for school and having difficulty in understanding what's wrong here.

For example, I want to create this table (automated SQL output):

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `jobsearch`.`Employer`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `jobsearch`.`Employer` 
(
`EmployerID` SMALLINT(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`IndustryID` SMALLINT(5) NOT NULL,
`Address` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`City` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL, 
`State` CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
`Zip` VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
`Phone` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,

PRIMARY KEY (`EmployerID`, `IndustryID`),
INDEX `fk_Employer_Industry1_idx` (`IndustryID` ASC),

CONSTRAINT `fk_Employer_Industry1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`IndustryID`) REFERENCES `job search`.`Industry` (`IndustryID`)

    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

I have this table that the foreign should be referencing (This table was created without any issue):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `jobsearch`.`Industry` 
(
`IndustryID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`IndustryName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`Region` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,

PRIMARY KEY (`IndustryID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Answer (score 1):

The datatype for the referencing column must match *exactly* that of the referenced column. You've defined `Industry.IndustryID as

```
`IndustryID` INT ...
```

and `Employer.IndustryID` as

```
`IndustryID` SMALLINT(5) ...
```

Change `Employer.IndustryID` to `INT` and you should be shiny.

Comment: Thank you!... I don't normally pop in here much but I still wanted to thank you.